# ¿Cómo creo carpetas y subcarpetas en Azure Storage Emulator con c#?

Tags: c#, blob, azure-storage

tengo una API que almacena archivos en un Blob Storage de Azure, pero necesito que se cree una carpeta en el contenedor y dentro de ella almacenar el archivo, por ahora solo puedo almacenar en la raíz del contenedor, tengo que crear la carpeta manualmente para mover los archivos ¿Hay alguna sentencia para crear carpetas en un Blob desde C#?, Gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Azure Blob Storage no está basado en un sistema de almacenamiento jerárquico pero puedes simularlo en el nombre del blob. Ejemplo: `carpeta1/archivo.txt`. [Leer más](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata#blob-names)

Answer (score -1):

Como tal no vas a encontrar una funcionalidad en c# del tipo `objAzure.CreateFolder("NombreFolder")`.

Lo único que debes hacer es que el nombre del archivo sea del tipo `CarpetaA/CarpetaB/CarpetaC/......./NombreArchivo.ext`